# how to reinitilizing a value in list

Tags: c#

I have problem with my list, I am trying to set Particle ID in below example, but I dont know why after I assign value to a particle and add to lstparticle, for second time inside the for all the particle ID are updated with new value but after it goes out of FOR, few values replace with the old value.

I think I might missed something. May I have your suggestion please regarding what is wrong? I need to reinitilize the ParticleID because I am receiving error in

```
fitnessValueListTemp[pTemp.ParticleID] = fitnessValueList[oldParticleID];
```

which oldParticleID shows 30. after debugging I observe that the above is the problem.

```
List<Particle> lstparticle = new List<Particle>();
```

inside the for initial value change to new value but after FOR few value change to old value!

```
for (int p = 0; p < Constants.SWARM_SIZE; p++){
   swarm[p].ParticleID = p;
```

Sample of particle class

```
class Particle 
{
   public Loc location { get; set; }
   public Vel velocity { get; set; }
   public int ParticleID { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in first image all the value initialized for first time, then second image show inside the FOR for second round and third image shows exactly when FOR finished.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that multiple elements in your list are referencing the same `Particle` class? Are you creating a new `Particle` object for each element in the list? Show us the code where you add the objects to your list initially.

Comment: I added code. I dont think, it is not possible...

Comment: Must be something really dumb, I see you are referencing `ID`. Is it `ParticleID`?

Comment: Please find private void calculatePBestAndGBest() in code...

Comment: @beautifulcoder: it is so funny, even I sent Particle ID in two places one before updatePBest and also inside the        updatePBest(); but it is referring to old value.

Comment: Please don't paste your entire program; that's far too much to read. Please not post the relevant part: where you assign `Particle` elements to the list.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline: please find  private void initializeSwarm()

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might want to use ElementAt() method on the list "swarm" instead of using indexer. It'll warn you in case you go out of bounds on the "swarm" list.

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi: Do u mean list[index] and list.elementAt[index] are different?

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi: same scenario is happened. I used elementAt instead of indexer

Comment: @rima same behavior but ElementAt method does check the size of your list.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline: I delete unnecessary part of my code

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi: I am getting error in fitnessValueListTemp[pTemp.ParticleID] = fitnessValueList[oldParticleID]; and the problem is that oldParticleID showing 30 which is impossible...the I found that my ID wont reinitialize...

Comment: definitely there is reference problem even I use a temporary list and after again I assign that one to swarm it goes back to old data... How I should solve it???

Comment: Sorry but the code is quite hard to read actually and I can't get one thing: I see that you have this line: p.missed = mt; How is this possible when p is of class Particle and Particle has no such property?

Comment: @rima there is far too much code to go through. You need to at least narrow it down to the problem area. Try stepping through with a debugger to isolate the section of code that's giving you trouble and post only those relevant sections.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline: problem solved...read my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to referencing... In C# when you copy a list it copy reference of the previous object to your new list, therefore it is recommended to developer to Clone their objects.

For colon my list I used below code:

```
public static T CloneObject<T>(T object)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, object);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

So for clone your object just call this function.

you need to serialize all the dependable classes related to T class.

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class ClassT
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Please also be aware of the difference between shallow clones and deep clones.

Comment: I found this article is very good and easy to understand... http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-of-instance-using-C-Sharp/